# How to convert multiple characters with Regular expression

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the characters `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`, and `'`, to their corresponding HTML entities: `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;`, and `&apos;`. For example, `"Tom & John"` should become `"Tom &amp; John"`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this coding...

```
alert(HtmlSpecialConversion("Tom & John"))


function HtmlSpecialConversion(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
```